# angular.js broadcast error: $rootScope.broadcast is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am adding items dynamically to an array of items and would like to let a directive know that there are new items. So inside the controller function addItem() I am trying to do the following:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $rootScope.broadcast("itemAdded");
    // I also tried: $scope.broadcast("itemAdded"); which isn't working
});
```

Problem: 
I'm getting the error:

> $rootScope.broadcast is not a function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its a typo its :

```
$rootScope.$broadcast(name, args)
```